# Odoo POS - Auto download invoice after validating

Tags: odoo, odoo-13, point-of-sale

See this video: https://youtu.be/PW-C3xKFBAE

Can anyone tell me how to change this PDF invoice template to a different one? When you click validate in the POS module it automatically downloads a PDF invoice. But I want this to download a different template design that is already installed in Odoo.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To change the default layout of invoice reports in Odoo then go to **General Settings > Companies > Configure Document Layout.** Here you can change the template of the report for the company.